# The matrix exponential lifting derivations to automorphisms

Tags: derivatives, lie-groups, lie-algebras, automorphism-group, matrix-exponential

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensionsl Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Denote its derivation algebra and automorphism group by $Der(\mathfrak{g})$ and $Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ respectively.  Let $exp$ be the matrix exponential, i.e.
$$exp(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{X^i}{i!}.$$

In general, we do not have $exp(Der(\mathfrak{g}))=Aut(\mathfrak{g})$. So I want to  know under what conditions of $\mathfrak{g}$ can make the above formula come true. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What counterexamples do you have for the general statement, maybe are they of a common kind?

Comment: I have read some references but not exactly in the above case. So I am sorry I don't know any counterexample. I have checked on  Google but failed. Do you know any reference about the relation between $Der(\mathfrak{g})$ and $Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ via the matrix exponential?